# How to prevent users from editing or removing the contents of ::before when using 'contenteditable'?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a text editor that displays a line number before each line. Users can edit the content thanks to the 'contenteditable' HTML attribute. However, this gives users the possibility to delete the ::before used to render the line numbers.

If I had to write a solution I should make the ::before un-editable, it already has display 'inline-block' so it should work, however, there is no way I can achieve this with CSS.

Code:

```css
.code-editor {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  counter-reset: line;
  font-family: monospace;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 30rem;
}

.code-editor:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.code-editor span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.code-editor span::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  color: #888888;
  content: counter(line);
  counter-increment: line;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  text-align: right;
  width: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<pre class="code-editor" contenteditable>
        <span>james</span>
    </pre>
```

I expect the editor to work as it currently does, it should for example still create a new span for each new line. However, I do not want users to be able to edit or remove the ::before that can be found inside each span.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the contenteditable attribut on the span instead of the pre element ?

```css
.code-editor {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  counter-reset: line;
  font-family: monospace;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 30rem;
}

.code-editor:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.code-editor span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.code-editor span::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  color: #888888;
  content: counter(line);
  counter-increment: line;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  text-align: right;
  width: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<pre class="code-editor" >
  <span contenteditable>james</span>
</pre>
```

Comment: Yes I did, but if you press enter a few times in your example, you will see that the new lines do not get a line number.

Comment: Sorry about that, do you have a specific reason to use the pre element ?

Comment: Not really no, but it is considered best practise when handeling code right?